# disable the main page while popup

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have used frame as below in default.aspx. main content is loaded in the frmContent. I have used popup in the content page. I have used javascript and css for disabling the page while popup. But it disables only the popup caller page. I need to disable default.aspx page while popup.

```
<frameset id="frmMainPage" rows="100,*" framespacing="0" noresize="true" border="0" frameborder="0">
<frame id="frmHeading" src="heading.aspx" border="0" frameborder="0"></frame>
<frameset id="frmMain" cols="250,*" scrolling="yes" framespacing="0" noresize="true" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame id="frmSidebar" src="under.aspx" name="sidebar"  scrolling="yes" border="0" frameborder="0"></frame>
    <frameset id="frmRemaining" rows="50,*" framespacing="0" noresize="true" border="0" frameborder="0">
        <frame id="frmMenu" src="menu.aspx" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0"></frame>
        <frame id="frmContent" src="content.aspx" name="content" scrolling="yes" style="overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: scroll" border="0" frameborder="0"></frame>
    </frameset>

</frameset>
```

Comment: you just need to give z-index max then your page....@sunila

Comment: Its not working. It is working only inside frmcontent. I need it to work for the main frame set, i.e. frmMainPage.

Answer (score 0):

For disable the background you have to call on more div with you pop.

When you call your popup using javascript just place another div having  `style(background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 50%) !important; opacity: 0.8 !important;)`

Make height and width full 100%. 
Make this div `display:none`

When you want to show the popup with that pop just make div `display:block`.

Hopefully it i'll b helpfull for you.